# Errors when loading tileset unity

Tags: arcore, tiles, api-key

I am starting with the integration of acore API and the tiles library for unity but I follow the steps I build the API key and it does not work for me in unity.

returns the following error:

> Errors loading tile:

I can't find a solution and I already created several API keys but none of them work and I followed the documentation given by Google and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because you have to pay

https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/

It's strange because it's impossible even just to try

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35447156)